# How do I Render R-Presentation (ioslide) Like this on RStudio?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

Show me how to render `R-Presentation` like this. I saw many examples as I read to learn how to make `R-Presentation` but each time I run them like normal `R code` on `RStudio` they refuse to render, though if I `ctr + v` it shows only the cover page. Like this my `MWE` that I know it is not a single slide presentation but all I get is [image: this]

````
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: ioslides_presentation
---

# In the morning

## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed

## Breakfast

- Eat eggs
- Drink coffee

# In the evening

## Dinner

- Eat spaghetti
- Drink wine

---

```{r, cars, fig.cap="A scatterplot.", echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

## Going to sleep

- Get in bed
- Count sheep
````

Please show me the `keyboard shortcut` to render `R-Presentation` like this on `RStudio` or `bottom` to `click` on the `RStudio` itself.

[image: RStudio]

Comment: Does this work: `Ctrl + Shift + K`?

Comment: The output I got with  `Ctrl + Shift + K` is the same  as https://i.stack.imgur.com/9il5r.png where are the other slides?

Comment: Try modifying your `.Rpres` file to `.Rmd`. Then you could try to knit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a `.Rpres` file type NOT .Rmd(Rmarkdown).

1. open a new text file in Rstudio
2. Save as `file.Rpres`
3. Use the appropriate syntax So RStudio know how to render your presentation

   ```
   In the morning
   =====================
   Exercise

   Breakfast
   =====================
   - Cereal
   ```

When you save the file with the code, Rstudio will have a `preview` button where the usual `knit` button is. when you click `preview` Rstudio will render the file appropriately.

[image]
I used [this link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200714023-Displaying-and-Distributing-Presentations) for research